# react-router doesn't render components on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

I using react-router and server side rending . but my server side not work with router . it change URL but doesn't render components
My server side code:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from "cors";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import App from '../shared/App';
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from "../shared/reducers/index";
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from "react-router-dom"
import { create } from 'domain';


const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors());
app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
let context = {};
const store = createStore(rootReducer)
const markup = renderToString(
<Provider store = {store}>
  <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
    <App />
  </StaticRouter>
</Provider>
)

const preloadedState = store.getState();

res.send(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SSR with RR</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">${markup}</div>
    <script>
      window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}
    </script>
    <script  src = "/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
  `)
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server is running ....')
});
```

And this is my App code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import List from "./List";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import { connect } from "react-redux";


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/list">List</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/home"> Home</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <Route component={List} path="/list" />
            <Route component={Home} path="/home" exact />
        </div>
       );
    }
};



export default connect(null,null)(App);
```

my List and Home components render string "Home" and "List"
my index.js code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../shared/App";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "../shared/reducers/index";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;

delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState);

ReactDOM.hydrate(
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
, document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is my all code it CHange URL but dont load component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem , i have to add withRouter from react-router-dom to app component

```
withRouter(connect(null,null)(App));
```